# Tapestry 5.4 core.properties override

Tags: java, properties, tapestry

I have a [tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) 5.4 project, and I want to override one element of the default **core.properties** file.

I tried to add to `login_en.properties` and `login_hu.properties` a new line (`core-default-error-banner=...`) but it do not override it.

Is there any way to overwrite it?

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to overwrite the header line of the Errors component, just specify your own message id in the page/component template like this:

```
<t:errors banner="message:your-translated-error-msg-id" />
```

Comment: Thx! It is the best solution for me; `<t:errors t:banner="${message:core-default-error-banner}" />`. :)

Answer (score 1):

To support other locales, just translate the built-in message catalog (property) files yourself: To have Tapestry use these new files, just put them in the corresponding package-named directory within your own app (for example, `src/main/resources/org/apache/tapestry5/core.properties`). More informtation can be found from [`Tapestry`](https://tapestry.apache.org/localization.html) site.

Comment: Thx for the answer! I tried out and it worked. But the other answer is better for me, because that way I can "override" it just on the login page.